# Unable to get the sum of rows for a matching string in Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to get the total sum(last column)of each 'District'
Ex:-Total of South Andamans and total of Nicobars
Please help
I have tried this
[image]

```
g1 = df1.groupby(['HS Code','District'])['April, 21 To February, 22 Value(US $)'].sum()
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

2 different solutions are given for groupby. From your question, it is not clear which type of final data structure you are looking for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"state":['A&N','A&N','A&N','A&N','A&N','A&N','A&N'],
                    'district': ['SA','SA','SA','N','N','N','N'],
                    'HS Code': [3,3,3,40,42,63,72],
                    'Feb Value': np.random.randint(200,300,7),
                    'Mar Value': np.random.randint(200,300,7),
                    'Apr Value': np.random.randint(200,300,7),})
df['Apr_district_by_sum'] = df.groupby(['HS Code','district'])['Apr Value'].transform(np.sum)
print(df)



state district  HS Code  Feb Value  Mar Value  Apr Value  Apr_district_by_sum
0   A&N       SA        3        252        249        277                  773
1   A&N       SA        3        268        267        268                  773
2   A&N       SA        3        295        241        228                  773
3   A&N        N       40        222        235        271                  271
4   A&N        N       42        225        226        202                  202
5   A&N        N       63        268        217        248                  248
6   A&N        N       72        292        257        270                  270
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"state":['A&N','A&N','A&N','A&N','A&N','A&N','A&N'],
                    'district': ['SA','SA','SA','N','N','N','N'],
                    'HS Code': [3,3,3,40,42,63,72],
                    'Feb Value': np.random.randint(200,300,7),
                    'Mar Value': np.random.randint(200,300,7),
                    'Apr Value': np.random.randint(200,300,7),})
df1 = df.groupby(['HS Code','district'])['Apr Value'].sum().reset_index()
print(df1)

 HS Code district  Apr Value
0        3       SA        735
1       40        N        206
2       42        N        207
3       63        N        235
4       72        N        275
```